# Entity Framework 4.3.1 and SQL Server CE

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I am following the official tutorial "EF 4.2 Model & Database First Walkthrough" using SQL Server CE 3.5 and alternative 4.0 versions. Unfortunately I always get an error:

> EntityException {"The underlying provider failed on Open."} on
>   db.SaveChanges() command.

Why MS have such poor support for its own database?

Comment: MS doesn't have poor support. You are doing something wrong. What is your connection string?

Comment: I have check connection string more than once. Also then I test connection to the database via VS2010 interface it sont return any errors